# How to distinguish two http errors cases: CORS blocking vs. server is down

Tags: javascript, http, error-handling, cors

This question is about an infrastructure where the are 2 back-ends and one front-end. So the back-end#2 is configured with CORS.

I am doing a `$.ajax` request on the back-end#2 and I need to programmatically distinguish between these two cases:

1. When the server was down
2. When a CORS blocking happened

Today the error is strictly the same in these two cases:

```
{
  "readyState": 0,
  "status": 0,
  "statusText": "error"
}
```

How to programmatically distinguish between these two error cases?

When there is a CORS issue, the browser `console.error` a specific message about CORS blocking but the need to display separated messages inside the application.

More details about my CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3310/foo' from origin 'http://bar.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: The only difference I can see is the time it takes for the error to come back. CORS fails almost immediately, but the server being down takes a bit.

Comment: :) yep, I can also override the 'console.error' method to detect some messages, but these are very crapy.
I was hoping something more reliable.

Comment: There is, by design, no way to distinguish between the two cases from frontend JavaScript code. (And overriding console.error won’t enable you to detect messages the browser on its own is logging to the console, such as CORS error messages.)

Comment: Thanks you sideshowbarker. What do you think about adding a healthcheck route opended to all origins, do you find it reliable?

Comment: The reliable way would be to use server-side backend code to make the request and check the status code of the response. So if that’s what you mean about adding a healthcheck route, then yeah, I guess that’d be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer:

Create a health check route on the server. It should be accessible from everywhere to detect that server is up.

Answer (score -1):

If its a cors error, the error code recieved should be 401 the following message should print on console

[image]

No ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN Header is present in the response.
If its a server down or anything related to server, you should receive a 5xx error code. Probably 500. So the you can check the error by distinguishing from their http status codes.

Comment: Can I ask you what is your client-side http request framework?

Comment: jquery, axios anything will do. The concept is same for every framework

Comment: (Because in my case the preflight OPTIONS return 204 (I can see it in network tab), but it produces an error at the framework level, and the two errors are the same: server down/cors pb.

Comment: if its a preflight request then it will result in 204 as in No Content. You are checking if the cors is enabled by the server. So no content is returned but a successful cors is enabled

Comment: I didn't get completely your message, Ayan. Can you please elaborate? How to distinguish a server down from a CORS issue.

Comment: If its a cors error you will likely to receive a 401 error while if its server down probably 500 error will be shown. If you re receiving a 204 error, its becuase of a preflight request where no content is returned but the request is successful which means cors is enabled and the server is working

Comment: A down server does not answer anything. You had a 401 response because of some unauthorized request, but it has nothing with a cors issue. I don't see any programmatic way to distinguish a cors issue from a server down.

Comment: try sending a request to your localhost server  being off. It will result in code 500